# Poor quality of animated gif export

Tags: graphics3d, export, animation

I have the following code:

```
g[
  t_, OptionsPattern[{ θ -> (0 &), u -> ({0, 0, 1} &), v -> ({0, 0, 0} &)}]
] := Graphics3D[{
   Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {5, 0, 0}}],  Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 5, 0}}],
   Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 5}}],
   Translate[
    Rotate[{
      Cuboid[{-1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}],Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {5, 0, 0}}],
      Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 5, 0}}],Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 5}}]
      },
     OptionValue[θ][t], OptionValue[u][t]], OptionValue[v][t]]
   },
  Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}},
  Boxed -> False,
  ViewPoint -> {2.82, 1.61, 1.20},
  PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {-2, 7}}
]

θf := Function[t, 0.5 Sin[t]];

uf := Function[t, {Sin[t], Cos[t]^2, Sin[t] Cos[t]}];

Animate[g[t, θ -> θf, u -> uf], {t, 0, 2 π}]

tt = Table[
   g[t, θ -> θf, u -> uf], {t, 0, 2 π, 2 π/100}
];

Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "ms.gif", tt]
```

but the quality of the animated GIF obtained is poor. How can I improve it? 
This is an example of a frame of the image:

[image]

Moreover, when the `Export` run, it in some way invalidates the `Animation` frame. Why? I mean that the running animation becomes the source code as in the following image. I also noted that `g` comes back to color blue, as if it was undefined.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, please add your version and OS info.

Comment: @Kuba: Mathematica Version Number 11.0.0.0, Platform: Mac OS X x86 (32-bit, 64-bit kernel). Operating system: OS X El Capitan 10.11.6.

Comment: For the second part of the question: `g` turning blue again indicates a kernel crash. I don't see this problem. I suggest you upgrade to 11.0.1.  It is almost always a good idea to upgrade to point releases. They fix bugs.

Comment: @Szabolcs: thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

Mathematica is not good at creating beautiful and small gifs. It won't reach the quality you can can with e.g. ImageMagick's `convert`. Therefore, I suggest you export your images as png

```
Table[Export[
  "~/tmp/imgs/" <> 
   ToString[PaddedForm[i, 3, NumberPadding -> {"0", "0"}]] <> ".png", 
  tt[[i]]], {i, Length[tt]}]
```

and then you call something along the lines

```
convert -delay 1x15 imgs/* +dither -layers optimize out.gif
```

in a terminal

[image]

I have to admit, that for this particular example, the gif created by Mathematica does look good as well. The file size, however, is larger by
almost a factor of 2.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try.